# Symfony - POST request forced to GET in jquery script using modal?

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, post

Probably a newbee question, but I didn't find any satisfactory answer crowling the web...

I'm using modals to manage CRUD on a DataTables screen. My backenn is Symfony 5 and I'm using Webpack-Encore. Everything is working fine... but the method of the request.

To make it short jQuery is creating a POST request, which is confirmed through the navigator control panel. However when I retrieve the Request on Symfony side it became a GET. I can cope with it using a GET but this is much more unsecure than using a POST.

My assumption is that the "transtyping" is due to the way Symfony is rewriting the URL with the firewall system (here my targetted URL is behind the firewall).

Could someone confirm that point, and even better is there something much cleaner than using GET ? I tried already 1/ to switch from $.ajax to $.post 2/ to use a before_send statement and various other workaround. This is why I think the "issue" is on Symfony side and not in jQuery nor the PHP controller.

My jquery:

```
$('#js_edit_button').on('click', function () {
    $.each($('#recordForm input'), function(){
        $(this).val(table.row('.selected').data()[$(this).attr('id')]);
    });
    $('#recordForm').attr('rowindex', table.row('.selected').id);
    $('#recordModal').modal('toggle');
});
$('#recordForm').on('click', '#save', function(e){
    const modifiedData = {};
    $.each($('#recordForm input'), function(){
        Object.assign(modifiedData, {[$(this).attr('id')]:$(this).val()});
    });
    console.dir(modifiedData);
    if (modifiedData.id == ''){
        console.dir('Creation');
        $.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate('app_suppliers_add'),
            // preferred method would be POST but does not work (due to security routing in Symfony ?)
            type: 'GET',
            data: modifiedData,
            success: () => {
                $('#recordModal').modal('hide');
                table.ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate('app_suppliers_edit'),
            // preferred method would be POST but does not work (due to security routing in Symfony ?)
            type: 'GET',
            data: modifiedData,
            success: () => {
                $('#recordModal').modal('hide');
                table.ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    };
  });
```

The controller, always returning "GET":

```
/**
 * @Route("/masterdata/suppliers/edit", name="app_suppliers_edit", options={"expose" = true})
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_CCC")
 */
public function editSupplier(Request $request)
{
    dd($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    ...
```

Any advice welcomed !!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you send all your ajax requests with a type: "GET" instead of type: "POST".

Try this

```
$('#js_edit_button').on('click', function () {
    $.each($('#recordForm input'), function(){
        $(this).val(table.row('.selected').data()[$(this).attr('id')]);
    });
    $('#recordForm').attr('rowindex', table.row('.selected').id);
    $('#recordModal').modal('toggle');
});
$('#recordForm').on('click', '#save', function(e){
    const modifiedData = {};
    $.each($('#recordForm input'), function(){
        Object.assign(modifiedData, {[$(this).attr('id')]:$(this).val()});
    });
    console.dir(modifiedData);
    if (modifiedData.id == ''){
        console.dir('Creation');
        $.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate('app_suppliers_add'),
            // preferred method would be POST but does not work (due to security routing in Symfony ?)
            type: 'POST',
            data: modifiedData,
            success: () => {
                $('#recordModal').modal('hide');
                table.ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate('app_suppliers_edit'),
            // preferred method would be POST but does not work (due to security routing in Symfony ?)
            type: 'POST',
            data: modifiedData,
            success: () => {
                $('#recordModal').modal('hide');
                table.ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    };
  });
```